# java printout elements from arrays one by one into separate lines using multi thread and for loop

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

Sorry for my lacking english. I am not a native english speaker. 
Today I learned about thread and now I am training.
I want to make a program which prints out elements from arrays one by one into separate lines using multi thread

```
   package Teeest;

import java.util.Arrays;


  public class THREADTEST {
  public static void main (String[] args){
    int[]a1 ={1,5,7,2,8,1,1,3,6};
    int[]a2 = {2,6,1,7,4,8,2,1,7}; 

        Thread2 t1 = new Thread2(a1,5);
        Thread2 t2 = new Thread2(a2,10);

        t1.thr.start();
        t2.thr.start();
        t1.thr.interrupt();
        t2.thr.interrupt();  

    }
    }

 class Thread2 implements Runnable {

 Thread thr = new Thread(this);
 private int []array;
 private int interval;
 Thread2(int[] ar, int time) {
    array = ar;
    interval = time*1000;

    }

    public void run(){
    while(true){
       try{
       Thread.sleep(interval);
       }
       catch(InterruptedException e){}
       for(int a: array){
    System.out.print(array[a]+" ");
    }
    }

   }
  }
```

This is my code and my output prints out whole arrays directly and even two arrays are not seperated into different lines. (I know I can use "\n" but in this case this does not work so well )

But I want java prints out elements one by one and into two different lines. How should I think?

_____________(line for elements from ar1)
(Enter) (Separate line)
_____________(line for elements from ar2) Of course thread should work while printing out elements one by one.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a PrintStream like System.out as there is no way to "go back a line". You would have to syncrhonize your threads: have thread1 print its array while thread2 waits, then a new line and then have thread2 print. But this of course would kind of defeat the purpose of using threads here.

Comment: Thanks! I should learn and read about synchronization...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just want the output of array1 on a line and the output of array2 on another line.
To do so, I would store the result in a StringBuilder for each Thread.

```
public void run(){
    while(true){
       try{
           Thread.sleep(interval);
       }
       catch(InterruptedException e){}
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for(int a: array) {
           sb.append(array[a] + " ");
       }
       System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

and you can remove this line

```
Thread thr = new Thread(this);
```

and call directly

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

and I do not understand the call to

```
t1.interrupt();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have a timer code(?) with me and I will use interrupt with that code. That is pretty easy. Now I just wrote interrupt method. Sorry for my lacking english. Because of my english you did not understand my problem perfectly. With your code, I can get array on two different lines. But the another problem was java prints out whole array directly. If I have array with elements 1,2,3,4 , the output should be so. 1(Thread works) 2 (thread works) 3 (thread works).... not 1 2 3 4 (thread) 1 2 3 4 (thread)

Comment: I guess you want the sleep inside the loop then to slow down everything. Otherwise you'll just see everything displayed at once. No idea though on how to display thread1 on line 1 and thread2 on line 2.

Comment: Aha.. Maybe I guess what do you mean.. Now I think using thread is meaningless to print out element one by one. Thanks for answer! :)